# Argument pass through php into bash file not working

Tags: php, linux, bash, loops, arguments

In my script I pass two argument into `Bash` file through `PHP` file.
PHP File:

```
$number_server = 7;
$server_name = "dbfs";
exec("/bin/bash drun.sh $number_server $server_name",$db_uptime);
foreach($db_uptime as $dbm_load){
echo $dbm_load."<br />";
 }
```

Bash File:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in seq $1; do ssh $2$i 'uptime;free -m;mpstat;cat /tmp/db2.info'; done &
pid=$!
sleep 2
kill -9 $pid
```

According to this it will show 7 records,but actually it shows only one record.Means `FOR` loop in `Bash` script runs only one time and second argument pass into bash is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You BASH script seems to be wrong. Replace that with:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=0; i<$1; i++)); do 
    ssh "$2$i" 'uptime;free -m;mpstat;cat /tmp/db2.info'
done &
pid=$!
sleep 2
kill -9 $pid
```

Comment: can we give `kill` time less then one second ?

Comment: Sorry didn't understand your comment. `kill` doesn't cause any delay.

Comment: sorry,can we give `sleep` time less then one second ?

Comment: sure, see this Q&A: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50722/need-a-loop-to-sleep-for-a-fraction-of-second